# Simplify equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a system of **two coupled differential equations**, which describe the **general case** of the **Two-Species-Interaction-Model**, in following fashion:

$$I: \frac{\delta p}{\delta t}=a_{1}\cdot p-b_{1}\cdot p^{2}-c_{1}\cdot p\cdot q$$
$$II: \frac{\delta q}{\delta t}=a_{2}\cdot q-b_{2}\cdot q^{2}-c_{2}\cdot q\cdot p$$

I want to find the **equilibrium state** of the system, in which both equations become 0. To achieve this i set the **left hand side** given by $\frac{\delta p}{\delta t}$ respectively $\frac{\delta q}{\delta t}$ to $0$ and tried to solve in terms of $p$ and $q$:

$0=a_{1}\cdot p-b_{1}\cdot p^{2}-c_{1}\cdot p\cdot q$ 
...(a few steps skipped) ...
**yielded:**

$$p=\frac{a_{1}-c_{1}\cdot q}{b_{1}}$$

$0=a_{2}\cdot q-b_{2}\cdot q^{2}-c_{2}\cdot q\cdot p$
...(a few steps skipped) ...
**yielded:**

$$q=\frac{a_{2}-c_{2}\cdot p}{b_{2}}$$

Clearly we see two equations with two unknowns $p,q$. I inserted $q$ into $p$, in order to get rid of an unknown, yielding:

$$p=\frac{a_{1}-c_{1}\cdot\frac{a_{2}-c_{2}\cdot p}{b_{1}}}{b_{1}}$$
...(a few steps skipped) ...

And now i am stuck with this equation for $p$:

$$p=\frac{\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}}-\frac{c_{1}\cdot a_{2}}{b_{2}\cdot b_{1}}}{1+\frac{c_{1}\cdot c_{2}}{b_{2}\cdot b_{1}}}$$

Especially i want to get rid of the $1$ in the denominator if its possible.

**How to simplify this thing further? Are there errors until this point?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
p &= \frac{\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}}-\frac{c_{1}\cdot a_{2}}{b_{2}\cdot b_{1}}}{1+\frac{c_{1}\cdot c_{2}}{b_{2}\cdot b_{1}}} \\
&= \bigg( \frac{a_{1}b_2}{b_{1}b_2}-\frac{c_{1}a_{2}}{b_{2}b_{1}} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{b_1 b_2}{b_1 b_2+{c_{1}c_{2}}} \bigg) \\
&= \bigg( \frac{a_1 b_2 - c_{1}a_{2}}{b_{2}b_{1}} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{b_1 b_2}{b_1 b_2+{c_{1}c_{2}}} \bigg) \\
&= \frac{a_1 b_2 - a_2 c_1}{b_1 b_2 + c_1 c_2}
\end{align}$$

And it's difficult to say whether you have made any mistakes as you didn't put your working down.

**EDIT:**

After going through, you made a mistake after substituting your equation for $q$ into your equation for $p$. You should have got

$$p = \frac{\frac{a_1}{b_1} - \frac{a_2 c_1}{b_1 b_2}}{1 - \frac{c_1 c_2}{b_1 b_2}} $$

After simplifying,

$$p = \frac{a_1 b_2 - a_2 c_1}{b_1 b_2 - c_1 c_2}$$

Comment: If you need anymore help, just ask below this comment. Also, if you're happy with my answer, could you please accept and upvote so we can close the question.